# Comparing and editing three lists of different lenght in python?

Tags: python

I have three lists:

```
a= [800, 900, 1800, 2000, 1500, 700]

b= [ 1800, 800 ]

c= [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

list a and list c are both made in a way that they form a graph, where  a[0] corresponds to c[0].

I wish to compare list a[] with list b[], and when the lists match, I wish to obtain the position in the list a so I can edit list c in that same position with a new value.

Example:

```
new value = 0.5

a[0] == b[1]

retrieve 0

c[0] = new value
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This seems like a convoluted approach to store a graph. What exactly `b` represents? The list of `a` values you need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
intersect = set(a).intersection(b)
for i,e in enumerate(a):
    if e in intersect:
        c[i] = newValue
```

Output:

```
>>> c
[0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a= [800, 900, 1800, 2000, 1500, 700]
b= [ 1800, 800 ]
c= [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]

for elem in b:

    if elem in a:

        c_index = a.index(elem)

        c[c_index] = "Some value"

print c
```

Comment: haha for no reason at all apparently I thought I was going to use it, but I guess I changed my approach. Fixed it thanks.